# failed to convert from String to type Long when field is LOB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

in the spring MVC application, I have Question entity class

```
@Entity
public class Question {

    @Lob
    @Column(name="QUESTION_TITLE")
    private String question;
...
}
```

I use Thymeleaf. for this field my view is bellow

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" 
th:field="*{question}" th:value="${question}" placeholder="">
```

my controller save method is

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveQuestion(Question question, BindingResult bindingResult){
        questionService.save(question);

        return "redirect:/admin/questions/all/";
    }
```

but when I submit, I have got error

```
Failed to bind request element: 
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type com.sendit.security.model.Question'; 

nested exception is 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'what';

nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
For input string: "what"
```

when I add @Convert(converter = QuestionConverter.class) attribute to the question field and implemented QuestionConverter method like bellow.

```
@Converter
public static class QuestionConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        return attribute.length();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I got the error again.

Comment: Could you please post your entire View (Thymeleaf) and Entity codes. I suspect you are trying to convert a single String value to a Question object (which is impossible since Question object is a complex type)

Comment: @Ahmet if you mean about view it is <form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/questions/save}"      modelAttribute="question" method="post" th:object="${question}">
I use lombok for entity class @ Getter and @ Setter

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. simply have changed "question" field name to another field name (like "title") and it works. it was caused because when in the View I want to send "question" attribute, it known like object and sent object hash value.